# \align* environment in array column

Tags: tables, align

So, I'm trying to make a column in my tabular environment be in `\begin{align*}` `\end{align*}`.

Been trying a few different things, but, I'm still a bit new to LaTeX.
I'm still playing around a lot trying to learn.
Therefore some short explanation on where I went wrong would be really nice.

So here is the thing I ended up with:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} %I think these two are the only relevant packages for this problem.

\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{align*}#1\end{align*}} %Redefining align* sens >{dec}<{dec}
%don't like extra {}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\caption{some cool caption} %guess this isn't relevant but..

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth} %Having a twocolumn doc so...
{|>{$}l<{$}|
                         *{2}{m{0.28\textwidth}|
                            >{\eq\bgroup}m{0.129\textwidth}<{\egroup}|}}

%The last column is where the magic is supposed to happen
%I'm also using multicolumns, not that I think it matters.
\frac{Cool}{equations} & Cool text & cool text & \frac{cool equations}{Broken column :'(
} \\
The coolness will be repeated for a few rows    \\

\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is it just easier to just use `\eq` in every column?
The errors I get is:
Missing } inserted. & \frac;
Missing $ inserted.;
Extra }, or forgotten $.;
Any help is welcome, and if the problem is not solvable maybe just a line or two where I went wrong in my thinking would really help me learn.

Best regards
**EDIT**: Adding what my code actually looks like and the result it produces.
My issue is that some columns look really ugly and I would like the second line of the cell to be centered (Which I assume the align* environment would do). I tried to use the `\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}`, but, it only gave me errors when I then changed `>{$}m<{$}` for `C`, or, just changed `m` to `c`. I hope this helps in clarifying what I'm trying to do.

```
\noindent%
\begin{table}[!b] 
\begin{center}
\onecolumn
\caption{Tables showing the different outcomes from changing the retention (re) and $k_{3}$ parameters in the aging model of \textit{S. cerevisiae}.
The model was constructed using the \citetitle{math} program with \citetitle{sbml}.}
\label{table:daughter}
\end{center}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|>{$}l<{$}|
                             *{2}{m{0.28\textwidth}|
                                >{$}m{0.129\textwidth}<{$}|}}
    \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Daughter}                                         \\
    \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$re=0$} 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$re=0.875$}                             \\ 
    \hline
k_{3}=0
    &   \smallskip
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{daughterC1,0.jpg}
        &   \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                =\frac{25}{3}=8.\overline{3}\approx8
            &   \smallskip
                \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{daughterC2,0.jpg}
                &   \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                =\frac{25}{3}=8.\overline{3}\approx8 \\
    \hline
k_{3}=1.6
    &
        \smallskip
            \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{daughterC1,16.jpg}
            & \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                =\frac{14}{3}=4.\overline{6}\approx4.7  
                &   \smallskip
                    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{daughterC2,16.jpg}
                & \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                =\frac{16}{3}=5.\overline{3}\approx5\\
    \hline
k_{3}=2.3
    &
        \smallskip  
            \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{daughterC1,25.jpg}
                &\frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                =\frac{1}{3}=0.\overline{3}
                    & \smallskip
                    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{daughterC2,25.jpg}
                    & \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                    =\frac{1}{3}=0.\overline{3}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|>{$}l<{$}|
                             *{2}{m{0.28\textwidth}|>{$}m{0.129\textwidth}<{$}|}}
    \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}    
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Mother}                                         \\
    \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$re=0$} 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$re=0.875$}                             \\ 
    \hline
k_{3}=0
    &   \smallskip
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{motherC1,0.jpg}
        &   \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
            \frac{53}{3}=17.\overline{3}\approx17
            &   \smallskip
                \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{motherC2,0.jpg}
                &   \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                \frac{53}{3}=17.\overline{3}\approx17                   \\
    \hline
k_{3}=1.6
    &
        \smallskip
            \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{motherC1,16.jpg}
            & \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
              \frac{6}{3}=2 
                &   \smallskip
                    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{motherC2,16.jpg}
                & \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                   \frac{3}{3}=1 \\
    \hline
k_{3}=2.3
    &
        \smallskip  
            \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{motherC1,23.jpg}
                & \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                =\frac{1}{3}=0.\overline{3}
                    & \smallskip
                    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{motherC2,23.jpg}
                    & \frac{\text{Number of division}}{\text{3 time units}}=\linebreak
                    =\frac{1}{3}=0.\overline{3} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\twocolumn
```

[[image: What it looks like[1]]

Comment: I am not sure this will work at all even outside of a `tabular` environment

Comment: You shouldn't be using `align`: just math mode is sufficient in the formula columns.

Comment: Ye I did that before, but, I thought that it was a bit ugly in some of the cells. But then again, maybe I should just be less picky with the esthetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of  column types have  some mismatch, the following work fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,mdwtab} %I think these two are the only relevant packages for this problem.

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[h]\centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{some cool caption} %guess this isn't relevant but..
        \label{tab:important}
    \begin{tabular}{|Ml|% with use of mdwtab 
                    *{2}{m{0.28\textwidth}|}
                     Ml|}
        \hline %just for better see table ...
    %The last column is where the magic is supposed to happen
    %I'm also using multicolumns, not that I think it matters.
    \frac{Cool}{equations} 
        & Cool text 
            & cool text 
                & \frac{cool\ equations}{Broken\ column} \\
        \hline% 
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{with use of mdwtab}    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
        \\
    \begin{tabular}{|>{$}l<{$}|% 
                    *{2}{m{0.28\textwidth}|}
                     >{$}l<{$}|}
        \hline %just for better see table ...
    %The last column is where the magic is supposed to happen
    %I'm also using multicolumns, not that I think it matters.
    \frac{Cool}{equations}
        & Cool text
            & cool text
                & \frac{cool\ equations}{Broken\ column} \\
        \hline%
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{without use of mdwtab}    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
        \\
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|>{$}l<{$}|% without use of mdwtab
                    *{2}{m{0.28\textwidth}|}
                     >{$}l<{$}|}
        \hline %just for better see table ...
    %The last column is where the magic is supposed to happen
    %I'm also using multicolumns, not that I think it matters.
    \frac{Cool}{equations}
        & Cool text
            & cool text
                & \frac{cool\ equations}{Broken\ column} \\
        \hline%
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{with use of tabular*}    \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
```

[image]

If you like to have displayed equations, than is sufficient to say `>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]\centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\caption{some cool caption} %guess this isn't relevant but..
    \label{tab:important}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}|% 
                *{2}{p{0.2\textwidth}|}
                 >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}|}
\frac{Cool}{equations}
    & Cool text
        & cool text
            & \frac{cool\ equations}{Broken\ column} 
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need structure in cells provided with `amsmath`'s  environments as are multi line equation, than is better (to my opinion) to write in cell (with colum type for example `>{$}m{\0.2\textwidth}<{$}`) something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]\centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\caption{some cool caption} %guess this isn't relevant but..
    \label{tab:important}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}|% 
                *{2}{p{0.2\textwidth}|}
                 >{$\displaystyle}l<{$}|}
\frac{Cool}{equations}
    & Cool text
        & cool text
            & \begin{aligned}
                x & = \frac{cool\ equations}{Broken\ column}\\
                  & = second\ line\ of\ equation\end{aligned} 
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking your time and helping me.
I will scrutinize your solutions, the packages you suggest and test it out/play around with it!
I have also realized that it would probably just have been smarter of me to post what I'm actually doing, even thou I thought it would be a---too big and too messy post then.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{...}
```

you can't call it like

```
\eq\bgroup ... \egroup
```

under *any* circumstance.

You can use the `collcell` package and not `align*` (which would add huge spaces above and below it), but a centered `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} %I think these two are the only relevant packages for this problem.
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\centering$\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}

\caption{some cool caption} %guess this isn't relevant but..

\begin{tabular}{
  |>{$}l<{$}|
   >{\collectcell\eq}m{0.3\textwidth}<{\endcollectcell}|
}
\frac{Cool}{equations} & \frac{cool equations}{Broken column} \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Note that you are using the `*` the other way around: for a one column table in a two column setting, use `table*`. The `tabular*` environment is for a different thing.

It's still not clear to me what you hope to fit in 13% of the text width.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking your time to help me.
I have posten the original code I'm working with and added a picture of the issue as well as some text to clarify!